# Create an entry in index without creating a Chapter or Section title

Tags: table-of-contents

My thesis is about a project I developed in a company. During the project, I generate several official documents that I'm appending at the end (using includepdf package). These documents have their own cover, so it's not necessary to create an almost blank page with only "Appendix A - Lorem ipsum", but if I don't include this I lose my reference in the index. What should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean an entry in ToC (table of contents) or really an index entry? If it is the ToC entry, then see option `addtotoc` in the documentation of package `pdfpages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{name that appear in the toc}
\includepdf{file.pdf}
```

the first option "toc" stays for table of contents (where you will add the entry).
the second let you to choose between chapter or section depending on your need.
the third is the name that appear in the index

(Maybe you should compile it twice to make it work)

Answer (score 2):

You can use option `addtotoc` provided by package `pdfpages` for the included pdf:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,chapter,0,First included pdf,incl:first}]{dummy.pdf}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,chapter,0,Second included pdf,incl:second}]{dummy.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Or with the same result:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\refstepcounter{chapter}\label{incl:first}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}{First included pdf}}
\includepdf[pages=-]{dummy.pdf}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\refstepcounter{chapter}\label{incl:second}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}{First included pdf}}
\includepdf[pages=-]{dummy.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Note that the order of `\clearpage`, `\addcontentsline` and `\includepdf` is important to get the right page number in ToC.

If there should be unnumbered chapter entries for the included pdfs:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{First included pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{dummy.pdf}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Second included pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{dummy.pdf}
\end{document}
```