# Table of contents including some "hand-made" entries

Tags: table-of-contents

I am currently finalizing an application which is mostly in LaTeX, but also includes a few PDF documents which will have been exported from MS Word.  So my table of contents will include automatic indexing from the LaTeX material, and hand-made entries that I'll have to put in myself to refer to the MS Word exported material.

What is the best way of doing this?  Do I run LaTeX a few times to create the table of contents, and then edit the toc file by hand to include the other page numbers?  Or is there a better way?  Can I, for example, automatically include the hand-made toc material after the automatic toc material?

Does my question make sense?

Comment: You can use `\addcontentsline{toc}{<sectioning type (i.e. chapter, section, subsection, ...)>}{<contents>}` in your `.tex` document in the appropriate place. That should give you entries in the TOC. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/453071/35864

Comment: If you use package `pdfpages` to insert the pdfs in your document, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444929/43317

Comment: Thanks - I've used `pdfpages` and its `addtotoc` parameter.  Works like a charm!